# Output of subprocess.check_output contains values that are not in the Python function's return value

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess.check_output` in order to get the return value of a script. The return value should be a single dictionary, but I'm noticing that in reality when I run `subprocess.check_output` the returned string is a list of dictionaries that are separated by `\n`.

To be more specific, I'm running machine learning code using the HuggingFace Transformers library. Inside the script that I'm running with `subprocess.check_output` there are multiple training epochs and log messages. However, at the end of the entire process, only one dictionary value is to be returned.

The script that I'm running prints the results to stdout after receiving them from main.

```
# Expected output
"{'eval_loss': 0.032146188743813565, 'eval_precision': 0.9019428152492669, \
     'eval_recall': 0.9138347260909935, 'eval_f1': 0.9078498293515358, 'training_time': '00:01:56'}"

# Actual output
'{"loss": 0.043012552560539916, "learning_rate": 6.445993031358885e-06, \
     "epoch": 0.8710801393728222, "step": 500}\n{"eval_loss": 0.009020083805239665, \
     "eval_precision": 0.962451684152402, "eval_recall": 0.9773831775700934, "eval_f1": 0.9698599647593434, \
     "epoch": 1.0, "step": 574}\n{\'eval_loss\': 0.032146188743813565, \'eval_precision\': 0.9019428152492669, \
     \'eval_recall\': 0.9138347260909935, \'eval_f1\': 0.9078498293515358, \'training_time\': \'00:01:56\'}\n\n'
```

I'm actually not even sure why some values for `epoch` aren't integers.

Anyway, would anyone know why this may be happening? I'm getting the feeling that `subprocess.check_output` may be returning everything that the script prints to stdout but I'm not sure. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: You are right, `subprocess.check_output` returns everything that was printed to stdout.

Comment: You are probably confused about what you are looking at. The actual output is JSON whereas you seem to expect a Python dictionary as a string.
Assuming you don't actually need the dictionary as a string, that part is easy; use `json.loads(output)` to convert the JSON string into a Python dictionary.
If you genuinely want that converted further back into a string, `repr()` does that; but this seems like a mistake and probably not something actually useful.

Comment: To further clarify the JSON representation you are looking at, the epoch values in the first two lines of the output are perfectly fine numerical strings, but examining the `repr` of the JSON data as a `str` causes Python to backslash the literal single quotes in the string. However, the third line of your sample output is not consistent with the first two; is that really genuine?